# Changes in Template Don't Affect Dependent Files

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, dreamweaver

I have a main template in dreamweaver (.dwt) that I have changed a link in because the address was incorrect.

When I save the changes to the main template, they aren't showing up in the html files which use the template.

I've tried saving the template, resaving the HTML file and "Putting" both of these files, but the changes don't show up.

I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: What version of Dreamweaver?

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine for the most recent versions except CC

Apply template changes to the current template-based document

1.Open the document in the Document window.

2.Select Modify > Templates > Update Current Page.

Dreamweaver updates the document with any template changes.

Update the entire site or all documents that use a specified template

You can update all the pages in the site, or only update pages for a specific template.

1. Select Modify > Templates > Update Pages.
2. In the Look In menu, do one of the following:

   - To update all the files in the selected site to their corresponding templates, select Entire Site, then select the site name from the adjacent pop‑up menu.
   - To update files for a specific template, select Files That Use, then select the template name from the adjacent pop‑up menu.
3. Make sure Templates is selected in the Update option.
4. If you don’t want to see a log of the files Dreamweaver updates, deselect the Show Log option; otherwise, leave that option selected.
5. Click Start to update the files as indicated. If you selected the Show Log option, Dreamweaver provides information about the files it attempts to update, including information on whether they were updated successfully.
6. Click Close.

Source: Copy pasted from here 
http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/editing-updating-deleting-templates.html